# Variable cannot be identified in lda

Tags: r, regression

I have received a data set about the ingredients of sweets of different brands, as well as information about prices in percent, sugar and profit in percent. The information on the ingredients are dummy variables, where 0 means that the characteristic is not present and 1 means that it is present. The other variables are numerical and represent the sugar content of a candy, the price of a product. Profit per Produt is a character variable. The goal is to select a statistical method to determine consumer preferences and to make a prognosis for a new product. I would like to implement the solution for this in R.

Since the categorical dummy variables and the categorical variable winpercent caused problems, I decided to convert all variables to the same data type

dpt(rbind(head(Candy.df, 10), tail(Candy.df, 10)))

```
dput(rbind(head(Candy.df, 10), tail(Candy.df, 10)))
structure(list(competitorname = c("100 Grand", "3 Musketeers", 
"One dime", "One quarter", "Air Heads", "Almond Joy", "Baby Ruth", 
"Boston Baked Beans", "Candy Corn", "Caramel Apple Pops", "Tootsie Roll Juniors", 
"Tootsie Roll Midgies", "Tootsie Roll Snack Bars", "Trolli Sour Bites", 
"Twix", "Twizzlers", "Warheads", "WelchÕs Fruit Snacks", "WertherÕs Original Caramel", 
"Whoppers"), chocolate = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), fruity = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L), caramel = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), peanutyalmondy = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), nougat = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), crispedricewafer = c(1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L), hard = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), bar = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), pluribus = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), sugarpercent = c(0.73199999, 
0.60399997, 0.011, 0.011, 0.90600002, 0.465, 0.60399997, 0.31299999, 
0.90600002, 0.60399997, 0.31299999, 0.17399999, 0.465, 0.31299999, 
0.546, 0.22, 0.093000002, 0.31299999, 0.186, 0.87199998), pricepercent = c(0.86000001, 
0.51099998, 0.116, 0.51099998, 0.51099998, 0.76700002, 0.76700002, 
0.51099998, 0.32499999, 0.32499999, 0.51099998, 0.011, 0.32499999, 
0.255, 0.90600002, 0.116, 0.116, 0.31299999, 0.26699999, 0.84799999
), winpercent = c("66.971.725", "67.602.936", "32.261.086", "46.116.505", 
"52.341.465", "50.347.546", "56.914.547", "23.417.824", "38.010.963", 
"34.517.681", "43.068.897", "45.736.748", "49.653.503", "47.173.229", 
"81.642.914", "45.466.282", "39.011.898", "44.375.519", "41.904.308", 
"49.524.113")), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L), class = "data.frame")



Candy.df <- read.csv("Candy.csv", header=TRUE, sep = ";", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

Candy.df <- sapply(Candy.df, as.factor)

dis <- lda(winpercent~chocolate+fruity+caramel+peanutyalmondy+nougat+crispedricewafer+bar+
         pluribus+hard+sugarpercent+pricepercent,data= Candy.df)


Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : Object 'chocolate' not found
```

Comment: What is the question here?  Is it "why am i getting an error?"  It might be because you're not keeping your data.frames straight.  You provided us with a dput of `cbc.df` then did `summary(Lidl.df)` and then tried LDA with `lda(..., data=Sweets.df)`.  Are these supposed to all be different data.frames?

Comment: Unfortunately your example is irreproducible. Please give code that run in a clear environment with libraries.

Comment: @DanY sorry it was my mistake. This is one data.frame. I renamed the names to one name. The error refers to the variable chocolate in the lda formula.

Comment: The error is telling you that there is no column with name `chocolate` in the data.frame `Lidl.df`.  Clear your global environment, read in `Lidl.df` with `read.csv()` as you are currently doing, and then check that there actually is a column called `chocolate`.